# Why is my moqui executable war file not allowing request to be found

Tags: moqui

I tried to follow the war generation instructions by changing the warName in `build.gradle` to `moqui-plus-runtime.war` and running `gradle addRuntime` and then `gradle deployTomcat`. There were no errors in the war build and I checked to see that the war file got installed as ROOT. I did not make any other changes (still using `MoquiDevConf` and I already had other system parameters in `MoquiInit.properties`.)

When I startup `tomcat8`, I don't see any errors in the log file and it says that it is loading `moqui-plus-runtime`, but when I make any request in the browser, the `localhost_access... log` shows `404` for any request.

Can you tell me what things I might of missed or how I would go about debugging this - there is very little info in the log files other than the `404` messages.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps to deploy to a Tomcat instance on the same machine. This is from memory as my production machine is currently offline for the next couple of weeks.

1. Edit tomcatHome to point to correct location
2. I personally run a `gradle cleanAll` first to remove old WARs etc
3. Run `gradle build`
4. Optionally run `gradle loadProduction` to load the production database, alternatively you can run `java -Dmoqui.conf=conf/MoquiProductionConf.xml -jar moqui-1.5.3.war -load -types=seed,seed-initial` so that you can pick which data types you want to load into production etc.
5. Stop Tomcat from running, probably optional but the next step deletes files & folders from a deployed tomcat instance.
6. Run `gradle addRuntimeTomcat` this task adds your runtime and also copies over the completed WAR into the Tomcat webapps directory if you set the location correctly in step 1.
7. Start Tomcat
8. Check Tomcat logs for any startup errors

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Sam. I had to drop this, but now I am back. I basically followed those steps but no luck. Can you tell me what the moqui.runtime value is in your MoquiInit.properties file is? My log file says that ROOT.war deployed and that is it. No indication that moqui is starting up. Everything in my ROOT dir seems right, but I wouldn't know what I was missing.

Comment: So the problem is what I suspected - missing files in the war because of a botched gradle file. I would have expected some error to be logged somewhere, but there was nothing. Had to actually pay attention to what I was doing!